# Use $interpolate in AngularJS to reduce automatically generated watchers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using the `ng-repeat` directive in AngularJS tends to produce a lot of watchers, as every row contains multiple `ng-bind` directives to display the row's data, respectively. Per site I have about 2.500 watchers: 100 rows, each row containing seven columns, each containing an `ng-bind` etc. This sums up to this huge amount of watchers.

I cannot use one-time binding, as the data might change over time (reloaded from backend, not modified by the user). Besides, pagination is not a solution, as the table is grouped in a way that prohibits every pagination approach.

Hence, I'm playing around with the `$interpolate` function of AngularJS. In particular, I want to extract the html of a single row to a new template, interpolate this row template in my JavaScript code, and add the concatenated rows to my `$scope`.

Now I have two questions:

1. Is this a bad approach in general? I still separate markup (a table row is described in a dedicated HTML file) from logic, but maybe there are other drawbacks I overlook at the moment.
2. How can I load the row template into a variable so I can pass it to the AngularJS functions?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the watchers are the root cause of your problem? Does profiling support that claim? Will pagination also solve the problem? [`ng-repeat` has been optimized to death before](http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/), but it should be the last resort and done only if *really* necessary.

Comment: You say you cannot use one-time bindings because the data might change - are you implying this data will change in the background and need updated, or are you implying the user might need to change the data? Because I have a jsFiddle that proves you can use one-time bindings and still have the user change the data: http://jsfiddle.net/consultwithmike/0y34u453/

Comment: Are you sure your browser is capable of rendering a list of 2500 complex nodes? Are you using `track by someUniqueID`?  Do you know about virtual lists?

Comment: god angular is so bad.. 100 rows hah :/

Comment: You have the right idea. Reducing watchers in `ng-repeat` is a great place to go. Or you may decide to replace with a directive that has only 1 watcher... so, what is nature of your need? Do you need to refresh the data only on data load?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with `$interpolate`?  If you need data binding with dirty checking then this approach doesn't seem like it saves you all that much.  Addressing the other question, having a directive that you can mark as `restrict: 'A'` with `replace: true` should allow you to make a <tr> tag with an angular directive.

Comment: if it's just displaying consider using `bind-once` or as per 1.3.* bind once notation `::model.variable`

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer you question 1, but q.2 (load template and use it in JS functions) can be achieved with this:

```
// add to $templateCache
angular.module("myApp", [])
.run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("myRow.html",
        "<tr><td>my name is: {{name}}</td></tr>");
}]);

//from your directive...
// retrieve from $templateCache and apply to element
var template = $templateCache.get('myRow.html');
var context = { name: "John Smith" };
var result = $interpolate(template)(context);

$element.append(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach will be replace the html on array change. You can use following directive to watch if the array is changed or not:-

```
app.directive("listChanged", function ($animate) {
    return {
        transclude: 'element',
        restrict: "E",
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
            var previousElement;
            $scope.$watch($attr.products, function ngIfWatchAction(value) {
                if (previousElement) {
                    previousElement.remove()
                }

                $transclude(function (clone, newScope) {
                    previousElement = clone;
                    $animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element);
                });

            });
        }
    }
});
```

And use the directive like this:-

`<list-changed products="products"><div ng-repeat="product in productList.products track by $index">{{::product}}</div></list-changed>`

You can find running example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shreyancejain/t47mLays/).

Hope it helps:)